# draw datatable stuck into the loop, keep showing processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, datatable

demo [video](https://watch.screencastify.com/v/OhmnpPBI4OlFyYhiLcnH), you could watch this 13sec video

**the table "table()" keep looping**

The data for d=table is captured correctly, but the processing grid has been showing up(ᗒᗣᗕ)՞

```
function table(sending_json) {
  const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

  var defaultData = {
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: true,
    serverSide: true,
    pageLength: 5,
    lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, 'Todos']],
    bDestroy: true,

    ajax: {
      url: newValue + '/api/log/files/list',
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: function(d) { // Use 'data' instead of 'd'
        d.search = d.search.value; 
        console.log(d);
        return JSON.stringify(d);
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken,
      },
      dataSrc: function (response) {
        console.log("DATA for table ", response);
        return response.data;
      }
    },

    columns: [
      { data: "filepath", title: "filepath" },
      { data: "filename", title: "filename" },
      { data: "extension", title: "extension" },
      { data: "modified", title: "modified" },
      { data: "size", title: "size" },
      {
        data: null,
        title: accountType === "OP" ? "" : "ACTION",
        visible: accountType !== "OP",
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          if (accountType === "OP") {
            return "";
          } else {
            return (
              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-edit-delete" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="" onclick="download_certain_ipc_log_to_txt(' + selectedDeviceId + ', \'' + row.filepath + '\', \'' + row.filename + '\')">Download</button>'

            );
          }
        },
      }
    ],

    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("xhr ERROR: ", xhr.responseText);
      console.log("status ERROR: ", status);
      console.log("error ERROR: ", error);
    }
  };

  var dataToUse = sending_json
    ? {
      ...defaultData,
      ajax: {
        ...defaultData.ajax,
        data: function(data) {
          sending_json.search = data.search.value;
          
          return JSON.stringify(sending_json);
        },
      },
    }
    : defaultData;

  // update certain_table 
  var certain_ipc_log_table_start_end_time = $("#certain_table").DataTable(dataToUse);

  // draw new table
  certain_ipc_log_table_start_end_time = $("#certain_table").DataTable(dataToUse);
  certain_ipc_log_table_start_end_time.draw();
}
function handleEndDateInput() {
  // Get the end date input element
  const endDateInput = document.getElementById("datepicker-end");
  const startDateInput = document.getElementById("datepicker-start");

  // Wait for 1 second to allow the user to finish typing
  setTimeout(() => {
  const endDate = endDateInput.value;
  const startDate = startDateInput.value;
  console.log("Start Date:", startDate);
  console.log("End Date:", endDate);
  
  // your code to send start and end dates to the server goes here
  const convertDateFormat_startDate = convertDateFormat(startDate);
  const convertDateFormat_endDate = convertDateFormat(endDate);

  console.log("convertDateFormat_startDate", convertDateFormat_startDate);
  console.log("convertDateFormat_endDate", convertDateFormat_endDate);
  // update JSON
  sending_json.start_datetime = convertDateFormat_startDate;
  sending_json.end_datetime = convertDateFormat_endDate;

  console.log("after 1 sec , run table()");
  setTimeout(() => {
  table(sending_json);
  console.log("sending_json", sending_json);
  }, 1000);
}, 1000);
}




setTimeout(() => {
  const endDate = endDateInput.value;
  const startDate = startDateInput.value;
  console.log("Start Date:", startDate);
  console.log("End Date:", endDate);
  
  // your code to send start and end dates to the server goes here
  const convertDateFormat_startDate = convertDateFormat(startDate);
  const convertDateFormat_endDate = convertDateFormat(endDate);

  console.log("convertDateFormat_startDate", convertDateFormat_startDate);
  console.log("convertDateFormat_endDate", convertDateFormat_endDate);
  // update JSON's start_datetime and end_datetime
  sending_json.start_datetime = convertDateFormat_startDate;
  sending_json.end_datetime = convertDateFormat_endDate;

  
  table(sending_json);
  console.log("sending_json", sending_json);
}, 1000);
```

---

So I modified it according to the logic (tried to let table() out of the loop),
so that the "table()" function will only be called once,  but the output is still the same இдஇ

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const endDate = endDateInput.value;
  const startDate = startDateInput.value;
  console.log("Start Date:", startDate);
  console.log("End Date:", endDate);
  
  // code to send start and end dates to the server goes here
  const convertDateFormat_startDate = convertDateFormat(startDate);
  const convertDateFormat_endDate = convertDateFormat(endDate);

  console.log("convertDateFormat_startDate", convertDateFormat_startDate);
  console.log("convertDateFormat_endDate", convertDateFormat_endDate);
 
  sending_json.start_datetime = convertDateFormat_startDate;
  sending_json.end_datetime = convertDateFormat_endDate;

  table(sending_json);
  console.log("sending_json", sending_json);
}, 1000);
```